# Possible to query the native inbox of a mobile from J2ME?

Tags: java, java-me, mobile, sms

Is it possible to query the native inbox (port 0 I suppose) of mobile from J2ME and then pull up the SMS for processing?

Comment: This would be a platform-dependant behavior. What handsets are you interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible.  The only API for accessing SMSs is [JSR 120/205](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=205), which only permits access to messages sent to a particular port number.