# Sending SMS to a non native port – other than port 0

Tags: java, java-me, mobile, sms, kannel

*Follow up to:*

> [Possible to query the native inbox of
>   a mobile from J2ME?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071358/possible-to-query-the-native-inbox-of-a-mobile-from-j2me)

How do I tell [Kannel](http://www.kannel.org/) to send an SMS to specific port other than the native inbox port(port 0 i suppose)?

My J2ME app on the mobile side listens to this particular port and will pick up the SMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a post on how to do it

http://nmlaxaman.blogspot.com/2009/02/kannel-send-sms-to-specific-port.html